# JavaScript function containing array methods not returning desired result

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm a JavaScript beginner and I've written the snippet below which in my mind should return an array: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], but instead it returns [5]. I realize there are better ways to achieve the result, but what I'm trying to understand is why my solution doesn't work.

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    array.concat(array.slice(i,i+1));
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    array.shift();
  return array;
};

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArray(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);
// JS Bin returns: [5]
```

The shift method appears to work, but the concat/slice code doesn't seem to alter the array. Why not? When I test the line as stand alone code it works fine. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why not exchange the first and last element and first +1 and last -1, and so on?

Comment: `arrayValue.reverse()`

Comment: `the concat/slice code doesn't seem to alter the array. Why not?` because neither `concat` nor `slice` modify the array. It's a boring explanation, I know, but it's the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) creates a *new* array without changing the original. [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) *modifies* the array it acts on.

Basically, you're generating a bunch of new sub arrays with `concat` but you aren't doing anything with them.

Comment: just personal. i appreciate your answers.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks :) I appreciate yours as well. High quality stuff.

Comment: Thank you! This gets at the heart of what I'm trying to understand (simple as it may seem). And thanks to everyone else who gave his or her advice — all good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

What Mike said: `array.concat(…)` does not modify `array`, it creates a new array which is then ignored.

It seems you only want to append a single value - that's what [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does:

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    array.push(array[i]);
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    array.shift();
  return array;
}
```

You probably also want to use a variable value derived from `array.length` instead of the constant `3`.

Answer (score 0):

There's answer how work `concat` and `shift` functions. Here's small snippet how to make this function easily by algorithmic approach if you don't want to create local copy of existing array.

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = array.length - 1;

  while (i < j) {
    var tempArrayElement = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tempArrayElement;

    i++;
    j--;
  }
}
```